# Configure LogLevel of Azure Function using environment variables

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

As per the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring), Functions V2 uses the [.NET Core logging filter hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#log-filtering) for configuration.

In the following example, an instance of ILogger is injected into the Run method of the function.

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger logger, ExecutionContext executionContext)
{
    logger.LogInformation("I don't want to see this in production!"));
}
```

When inspecting the ILogger object, each LoggerInformation element has MinLevel of null which seems to log all levels.

In production, I only want to log at the Error level. I would like to be able to configure this using an environment variable but I cannot find any documentation which explains how to achieve this. I have tried adding the following environment variable to no effect:

```
"logging__logLevel__Default: "Error"
```

Comment: Have you checked logging configuration in [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#logging) or you only want to work with environment variable?

Comment: I would like to see if it's possible to control LogLevel using environment variables but I wasn't familiar with the host.json file. When debugging the Function locally using the emulator, I can see that a host.json file is automatically generated but does not contain any logging config. When I edit the file manually I can successfully set the log level. Can I control the generation of this file when developing locally?

Comment: Manual edit is the only way, generation is controlled by Azure function template engine for VS.

Comment: How can you change that value (host file or other) live? I don't want verbose to be enabled by default, but I might want to enable it for a few minutes without having to redeploy... Is that possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looking at the code ([1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/ad02f1cbfa1db26bea8ecc9ac62245d6481c8d30/src/WebJobs.Script/Config/ScriptHostOptionsSetup.cs), [2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/ad02f1cbfa1db26bea8ecc9ac62245d6481c8d30/src/WebJobs.Script/Config/ConfigurationSectionNames.cs), [3](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/ad02f1cbfa1db26bea8ecc9ac62245d6481c8d30/src/WebJobs.Script/Config/ScriptEnvironmentVariablesConfigurationSource.cs)) for azure functions runtime, this appears to be possible. You have to set it as

```sh
export AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logLevel__default=Error
```

This works for other `host.json` settings too

```sh
export AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensions__http__routePrefix=just-another-prefix
```

Comment: Here's the specific [line of code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/6fc1a164e086029acecd4aa208a0ec3f4d1dea1f/src/WebJobs.Script/Config/ScriptEnvironmentVariablesConfigurationSource.cs#L44) with the double underscore

Comment: This is now covered in the [Azure Function Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#override-hostjson-values)

Answer (score 10):

Extending the answer given by [Pramod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56397459/4292717)

In the portal, navigate to the Azure Function, goto the Configuration blade and press 'New application setting' :

- Name: `AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logLevel__Default`
- Value: `Error`

NB. Don't forget you need to press OK, then also press Save on the Configuration blade.