# How to change logging verbosity for an Azure Function via Azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

All the doco I've found shows how to set the logging verbosity of an Azure function via the hosts.json file with the config below.

I would like to change the logging verbosity without having to redeploy this file.

However, I can't see any samples where the verbosity is being set via the portal. I've tried using portal Application Settings with the App Setting Name logging:logLevel.default but that has no affect.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
    "logLevel": {
      // For all functions
      "Function": "Trace",
      // Default settings, e.g. for host
      "default": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

Please note I'm running from a package file which is the recommended approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set these settings in host.json file without re-deploy. There is a host.json setting on the azure portal as well.

Please go to your function app -> Overview -> Function app settings, then you can see there is a host.json, you can set log level there, then save and no need to re-deploy(And remember to change the edit mode of your function app as Read/Write as described in screenshot below).

[image]

**remember to change the edit mode of your function app as Read/Write**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ivan Yang I'm running from a package which is the recommended approach so get the following message. It would be nice if debug verbosity could be modified with out a whole new deployment. "Your app is currently in read-only mode because you are running from a package file. When running from a package, the file system is read-only and no changes can be made to the files. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting."

Comment: I think it's impossible to change loglevel from app settings. If you cannot change the host.json since it's read only, you'd better re-deploy it. And regarding why the loglevel does not take effect in app settings, you can see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53405020/configure-loglevel-of-azure-function-using-environment-variables).