# Database.Migrate fails on docker container restart

Tags: c#, docker, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, entity-framework-migrations

I have deployed my ASP.NET Core Web API on Docker. My application interacts with SQL Server in a Docker container also.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
 version: '3'
 services:
     db:
         image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
         container_name: db
         ports:
             - 1533:1433
         environment:
             - TZ=Asia/Tehran
             - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
             - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=******
         user: root
         volumes:
             - ./mssql:/var/opt/mssql/data
    kava-service:
        image: service:1.0.0
        container_name: service
        expose:
            - 9001
        ports:
            - 9001:9001
        depends_on:
            - db
        environment:
            - ASPNETCORE__ENVIRONMENT=Production
            - TZ=Asia/Tehran
            - AUTO__MIGRATE=true
            - ConnectionStrings__BusinessDomainConnectionString=Server=db;Initial Catalog=Kava.BusinessDomain;User ID=sa;pwd=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
            - ConnectionStrings__RecordsConnectionString=Server=db;Initial Catalog=Kava.Records;User Id=sa;pwd=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

When I run the docker container (using `docker-compose`), it works fine. But if I restart this container, it doesn't work and the application exits with this message:

> Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'Kava.BusinessDomain'  [CLIENT: 172.18.0.4] kava-service
> Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Database 'Kava.BusinessDomain' already exists. Choose a different database name.

When I delete this database everything works but I don't want to delete it.

Everything is fine in development (Visual Studio I mean), but in production (Docker), migration doesn't work as expected.

Here is my migration command:

```
 BusinessDomainContext businessDomainContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBusinessDomainDatabaseFactory>().Get() as BusinessDomainContext;
 await businessDomainContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your migration process might be attempting to create an already existing database. Your [ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/introduction-to-aspnet-core?view=aspnetcore-8.0) application should check if the database exists and apply only necessary migrations instead of attempting to create a new database each time (using ["resolving a service at app start up"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0#resolve-a-service-at-app-start-up)).

```cs
using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var context = services.GetRequiredService<BusinessDomainContext>();

    // Check if the database exists and apply migrations if necessary
    if (context.Database.CanConnect())
    {
        // context.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any() is another option.
        if (!context.Database.GetAppliedMigrations().SequenceEqual(context.Database.GetMigrations()))
        {
            await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Logic to handle the scenario where the database does not exist
        // That might include creating the database, if that is your intention
    }
}
```

The `Login failed for user 'sa'` error could be a symptom of the SQL Server container not being fully ready when your application attempts to connect. You could test implementing a retry policy for database connections, using a [connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings), as seen in "[Implement resilient Entity Framework Core SQL connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-resilient-entity-framework-core-sql-connections)".

```cs
services.AddDbContext<BusinessDomainContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("BusinessDomainConnectionString"),
        sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
        {
            sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                maxRetryCount: 5, 
                maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                errorNumbersToAdd: null);
        }));
```

That would sets up a retry policy where the application will try to reconnect to the database up to five times with a 10-second delay between retries.

---

Also, try to enhance logging around these operations, for debugging purposes.
And use `docker-compose up -d; docker-compose logs -f` to  to run services in the background and then follow any output from your containers.

Inside your application, you can use a logging framework to log messages. In an ASP.NET Core application, you can use the [built-in logging framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-8.0). You can configure it in your `Program.cs` or `Startup.cs` file to log messages to the console, which will then be picked up by Docker.

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddConsole();
        });
```

And you can set the [`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0#environments) to `Development` to get more detailed logs from your ASP.NET Core application.

That can be done, in your `docker-compose.yml` file, with a `command` field to your service to override the default command that your Docker image runs when a container is started.
That can be useful for adding flags or arguments to enable more verbose logging.

For example, if your application accepts a `--verbose` flag to enable more detailed logs, you could add a `command` field like this:

```
services:
  service:
    image: service:1.0.0
    command: ["./your-app", "--verbose"]
    # rest of your service configuration
```

In the context of an ASP.NET Core application, you can control the log level with environment variables. For example, you can [set `Logging__LogLevel__Default`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56397459/6309) to `Debug` or `Information` to get more detailed logs:

```
services:
  service:
    image: service:1.0.0
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE__ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logLevel__default=Debug
    # rest of your service configuration
```

That will set the log level to `Debug` for all categories of logs in your application. You can also set the log level for specific categories by using [environment variables like `Logging__LogLevel__Microsoft=Information`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#set-log-level-by-command-line-environment-variables-and-other-configuration).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is a issue with `Database.Migrate` as it should be idempotent (like what it does in development). I have opened this issue (https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32669) in github. maybe someday Microsoft resolves it.

Comment: @RezaNoei OK, I will follow the resolution of that issue with interest.

Comment: @RezaNoei Darn it: [issue 32669](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32669) has been closed as "not planned".

Comment: Tnx, It's Microsoft after all 